# String equality in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a firebase function in NodeJS (no typescript), and I'm trying to test for string equality. I've tried many ways as shown below and cannot seem to get it working.

The `carrier` variable is a string and does not have whitespace, so I'm lost on what else could be the issue, stopping the equality.

```
const carrier = customer.preferred_carrier

console.log(carrier) // output is: 'UPS'
console.log(typeof carrier) // output is: string
console.log(String(carrier.replace(/\s+/g, "")) == 'UPS') // output is: false
console.log(String(carrier).valueOf() == 'UPS') // output is: false
```

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(carrier.length)`? Btw, there is no need to call `String`. The return value of `replace` and `carrier` itself are already strings.

Comment: can't reproduce.,getting true last two statements

Comment: Is it possible you have two different encodings in play?

Comment: Do a `console.log(encodeURIComponent(carrier))` just to make sure there are no invisible characters etc

Comment: It has to be something with to do with how the object is interpreted by firebase. I get false with all of these suggestions.

Comment: `customer.preferred_carrier` is referencing a json object

Comment: string.length returns 5 so that's it. Thanks @FelixKling

Comment: === doesn't work for me in firebase functions for integers or strings @doug-stevenson so I have to use == and disable es-lint for that line.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure this is not working as you expect?
[image]

Comment: I got false on the backend, but true when I run locally.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
console.log(carrier.toUpperCase().trim() === 'UPS')
```

Comment: Why would the Question Asker need to use this code? Please explain how this code works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the following regex:

`carrier.replace(/[^\w\s!?]/g,'')`